# What is helical Dirac nature?

Tags: electric-fields, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, topological-insulators, spin-models

[image]

A concept in Spintronics which can not be found on Wikipedia. The picture is from a review of Spintronics of 2016 by Fert.

Comment: It can actually be found on Wikipedia, but the page is woefully incomplete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helical_Dirac_fermion

Comment: That's the question:-(